# How to write a customized database adapter in Zend Framework e.g. Mysqli_Customized?

Tags: database, zend-framework

I want to create a customized adapater like Mysqli because I want to add some functions in it.

How can I do it?

Tell me the best possible way to achieve.

The prime reason why I want to create a customized adapter is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550575/determine-mysql-query-type-in-zend-framework)

Many thanks iun advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of would be to extend `Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli`

```
class My_Db_Adapter_Mysqli extends Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli
{
    // customisations
}

$db = Zend_Db::factory('My_Db_Adapter_Mysqli', $config);
```

Comment: Thx for your prompt response Phil. I am checking it.