# Change the path of Database Adapter class in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, adapter, customization

I have written a customized Database Adapter extending Mysql Adapter (Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli) and my application.ini looks as under :-

```
resources.multidb.master.adapter = PDO_MYSQLCUSTOMIZED
resources.multidb.master.host = HOSTNAME
resources.multidb.master.username = USER
resources.multidb.master.password = PASS
resources.multidb.master.dbname = DB
```

(Reason why it did so is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550575/determine-mysql-query-type-in-zend-framework)?)

Now my problem is I have to save Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysqlcustomized in default path i.e. `/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysqlcustomized.php.`

I dont want to save`Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysqlndtv` class in library.

What should I do?

Comment: You should go back over your previous questions and accept some answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is rename your class to something like `My_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`, store it in `library/My/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and add / set these in your config file...

```
autoloaderNamespaces.My = "My_"
resources.multidb.master.adapter = "My_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql"
```

Comment: Just giving this a try Phil. Will revert after few moments

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the regular adapter ini setting:

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
```

and then define the prefix/namespace to force it look in your local library (assuming you have YourLibs/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php)

```
resources.db.params.adapterNamespace = "YourLibs_Db_Adapter"
```